# Simplify the last step of this differentiation

Tags: calculus

$$y = (3x+4)^4(5x+3)^{-3}$$

I don't know how they simplify the last step to get to the answer of: $$\frac{3(3x+4)^3(5x-8)}{(5x+3)^4}$$

Comment: please elaborate what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Big(\frac{(3x+4)^4}{(5x+3)^3}\Big)'=\frac{\big((3x+4)^4\big)'(5x+3)^3-(3x+4)^4\big((5x+3)^3\big)'}{(5x+3)^6}= \\ = \frac{12(3x+4)^3(5x+3)^3-15(3x+4)^4(5x+3)^2}{(5x+3)^6}=\frac{12(3x+4)^3(5x+3)-15(3x+4)^4}{(5x+3)^4}= \\ =\frac{(3x+4)^3\big(12(5x+3)-15(3x+4)\big)}{(5x+3)^4}=\frac{(3x+4)^3(60x+36-45x-60)}{(5x+3)^4}= \\ =\frac{(3x+4)^3(15x-24)}{(5x+3)^4}=\frac{3(3x+4)^3(5x-8)}{(5x+3)^4}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!  My book just says "simplify" and I'm not sure how they got through all those steps that you provided above.